# What does it mean for an inverse limit to be 0?

Tags: algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy-theory

I am currently working on the infinite-dimensional case of the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence
where a lot of inverse limits are needed to state useful conditions on convergence.

In particular let $X$ be a CW-Complex, $E$ a CW-Spectrum and $E*$ the induced generalized cohomology theory.

Then what does
$$ \varprojlim E^*(X,X_n)=0$$
mean? Is there a way to intuitively understand inverse limits being zero?

If one had an inverse System $(E^k,d_k)_k$ in an abelian Category with $E^{k+1}=E^k$ for all $k>r$ would the inverse limit be $0$?

Comment: The answer to the last question is "no". It depends on $d_k$. If all $d_k$ are identities, then the inverse limit is simply (any among equal) $E^k$.

Comment: Assume we deal with algebraic objects and an inverse system $(A_i, f_{ij})$. Then $\varprojlim A_i=0$ means that given any $x\in A_i$, $x\neq 0$ there is $j$ such that $x\not\in \text{im} f_{ij}$. I think that's the best thing we can deduce in general.

Comment: The condition given in the comment by @freakish is sufficient to make the inverse limit zero, but it is not in general necessary. It is necessary when the index set is countable, but not in general.

Comment: @AndreasBlass to be precise when the indexing set is $\mathbb{N}$ (with the natural order), not necessarily any countable indexing set, right? Anyway, yes, that was my assumption.